# How to display special characters in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL server 2008 and have the column in my table set to nvarchar. Data with special characters are getting stored wrongly in this table. Eg: this is one entry

Need to check if doesnâ€™t comes as doesnâ€™t itself and donâ€™t comes asdonâ€™t itself and ensure closure of issues.

The garbage â€™ should actually be an apostrophe ('). I have checked my collation string. At database level it is SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2 and at server level it is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

I know for sure the encoding set everywhere else in my application is UTF-8.

How do I store the data correctly in my table? Do I need to change my SQL queries or any settings in the database?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you're observing two things:

1. Always use `NVARCHAR` as datatype for your columns
2. Always make sure to use the `N'....'` prefix when dealing with string literals (for example in your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements)

With those two things in place, SQL Server has no trouble at all storing all Unicode characters you might throw at it...

Comment: Thanks for the reply marc. I am having my columns set to nvarchar as datatype and I did read about the second point a while ago. But I am stuck at how to use it in my insert string. I am using Spring JDBC Template to access the tables and following is my insert query:\

Comment: getJdbcTemplate().update(insert into EmployeeTimeData (workText) values (?) new Object[]{tempBean.getWorkText()})  I get the data as mentioned in the question retrieved from  a bean.

Comment: @SandeshShanbhag: I don't know Spring JDBC at all - but I would hope they'd be using a Unicode-compatible method to insert their data!

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to know where I can prefix the N in the query.