# Special Character in SQL

Tags: sql-server, ascii

I have a problem with a special character inserted in a table of SQL Server 2008 R2. 
The point is that when i'm trying to insert a string with the character º (e.g. 3 ELBOW 90º LONG RADIUS) in the table this appears like this: 3 ELBOW 90� LONG RADIUS, and when i'm trying to select all the rows that contains the character � the result is null.

I tried to make the select with ASCII by making this:
select * from itemcode where description like '%'+char(63)+'%'

and make this to know that the ASCII of that symbol is 63:

select ASCII('�')

But that doesn't work.
What i must do to select all the rows that have that character and what should i do to make that SQL recognize the character º?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried character 167?

Comment: Is the data type for the field varchar or nvarchar? You may want to try nvarchar if you are not using it.

Comment: It could also be a problem with your SQL client, either transmitting the wrong values or displaying them incorrectly.

Answer (score 9):

The [degree symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_symbol)

```
U+00B0 ° degree sign (HTML: &#176; &deg;)
```

is not an ASCII character and generally requires an NVARCHAR column and a `N''` string literal. (except for codepages etc that support the symbol)

63 is the code of the [question mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark), which is the fallback for your inverse question mark in ASCII:

```
select UNICODE('�') => 63
select UNICODE(N'�') => 65533
```

where 65533 is the [Unicode Replacement Character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) used to display characters that could not be converted or displayed.

Comment: But how can i select all the rows that contains that Unicode Replacement Character? I tried 
select * from itemcode where description like '%'+char(65533)+'%'
But doesn't work

Comment: you should insert your data so that the Replacement Character is not even stored. try N'°' rather than '°'.

Comment: Thanks for the response but if the information is already stored and i want to see all the rows that have this issue what can i do?

Comment: use NCHAR(65533) to create the Unicode character: N'%'+NCHAR(65533)+N'%'

Answer (score 3):

when I run this:

```
print ascii('º')
```

I get 186 as the ascii code value, so try:

```
select * from YourTable Where Description like '%'+char(186)+'%'
```

to see all the ascii codes run this:

```
;WITH AllNumbers AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number+1
        FROM AllNumbers
        WHERE Number<255
)
SELECT Number,CHAR(Number) FROM AllNumbers
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 255)
```

**EDIT** op stated in a comment that they are using nvarchar columns.

forger about ascii, use [NCHAR (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182673.aspx) to output a degree symbol:

```
print '32'+NCHAR(176)+'F' --to display it

select * from YourTable 
    Where Description like '%'+NCHAR(176)+'%' --to select based on it
```

and use [UNICODE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx) to get the value:

```
print UNICODE('°')
```

returns:

```
176
```

Comment: run `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('YOUR_DATABASE_NAME', 'Collation') SQLCollation;`, I get `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, so you probably get something different.

Comment: if you are using nvarchar as noted in another comment, you need to **forget about SQL Server's `ASCII()`** command remember it stands for `American Standard Code for Information Interchange` and was set up long before internationalization was considered and doesn't include enough special characters.  you need to **use UNICODE ( 'ncharacter_expression' )**

Comment: When i run 
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('YOUR_DATABASE_NAME', 'Collation') SQLCollation 
i get Latin1_General_CI_AS

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 10 * from table_name 
where tbl_colmn like N'%'+  NCHAR(65533) + N'%'
```

the function NCHAR(65533) will return the character your're looking for.

Comment: Not work for me. Text is - '34��������'. `SELECT unicode(SUBSTRING(text, 3, 1))` => result: **65533**. `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[bla] WHERE [text] like N'%['+nchar(65533)+N']%'` => rusult: 0 rows. But, i know about more than 19k rows with � character.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making sure that it is an NVARCHAR, I would use something like this

select (N'�')

[How to display special characters in SQL server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512496/how-to-display-special-characters-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but recently faced the same problem, and found solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2754165e-7ab7-44b0-abb4-3be487710f31/black-diamond-with-question-mark?forum=transactsql)

"The best way I know of to find it or get rid of it in SQL is to check for it using a binary collation. For example"

```
Declare @Foo Table(PK int primary key identity, MyData nvarchar(20));
Insert @Foo(MyData) Values (N'abc'), (N'ab�c'), (N'abc�')
Select * From @Foo Where MyData Like N'%�%'

-- Find rows with the character
Select * From @Foo
Where CharIndex(nchar(65533) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, MyData) > 0

-- Update rows replacing character with a !
Update @Foo
set MyData = Replace(MyData, nchar(65533) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, '!')

Select * From @Foo
```