# Stored procedure is failing when one of the values contains specials characters

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with a special character. Because when there is a ' character then the code will fail. How can I make it work with special characters by using a stored procedure below.

```
        internal bool AddRecord()
        {
             string SQL = "exec SqlInsert ";

             SQL += "'" + _sqlComputer + "', ";
             SQL += "'" + _lastUpdatedBy + "', ";
             SQL += "'" + DateTime.Now + "', ";
             SQL += "'" + _softwareName + "' ";

             return SqlDatabase.Overig(SQL);
        }
```

Comment: Slightly unrelated - don't build SQL queries by appending strings (It makes you more vulnerable to SQL injection). Use an SQLCommand object and add parameters to it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reply. I never did this before. Do you have an example for me?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542517/call-a-stored-procedure-with-parameter-in-c-sharp - it shows you how to use a stored procedure with parameters.

Comment: Ah great. I'll let you know when it works! :) Thanks

Comment: The parameters suggested by @PhonicUK should solve your apostrophe problem as well.  Plus, if you have a stored procedure, why do you have sql in your .net application.

Comment: What do you mean Dan Bracuk with .net application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SqlInsert", sqlCon);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = _sqlComputer ;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _lastUpdatedBy ;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param3", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param4", SqlDbType.Varchar,50).Value = _softwareName ;

sqlCon.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);
sqlCon.Close();
dr.Dispose();
cmd.Dispose();
```

**Edit As Per Your Requirement**

Instead of Passing Values like

```
SqlDatabase.Overig(SQL);
```

Do this

```
SqlDatabase.Overig(_sqlComputer,_lastUpdatedBy,DateTime.Now,_softwareName);
```

and make changes in Overig method like

```
Overig(String sqlCom, string UpdatedBy, DateTime dat, string software)
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SqlInsert", sqlCon);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = sqlCom;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = UpdatedBy;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param3", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dat
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param4", SqlDbType.Varchar,50).Value = software;

sqlCon.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);
sqlCon.Close();
dr.Dispose();
cmd.Dispose();

 }
```

Comment: +1, even better, if you use the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement, for SqlCommand and SqlConnection,

Comment: The SqlCommand I have that in another class. My code just send just one parameter to the other class with one record. So I just need a return. How can I use it when I have the SqlCommand in another class?

Comment: But the code you are showing in your question. you are passing string to some class. What exactly you wanna do ??

Comment: You can pass the stored proc parameters to the class you are talking to instead of passing SqlCommand Object and use this code in that class

Comment: I'm not so great in SQL :P Could you help me more with this? Because this is more safe I think

Comment: I'll test it :) I'll let you know!

Comment: Does the actually solve OP's problem? the character escape thing?

Comment: @JensKloster well the way he/she doing was not according to MSDN.

Comment: so define it there.. SqlCon is SqlConnection here

Comment: @RajeevKumar I agree. But it seems out of scope to me. Everyone is always so hyped about SQL injection :) I don't understand why. Yes OP's code is vunarable to SQL Injection, but so what? Thats not why he put in on SO (i think) :)

Comment: @JensKloster I agree to u. But don't you think we should tell some one right way to do the things. This is for what SO is here. To help others in efficient way..

Comment: @RajeevKumar In my humble opinion, a good answer must as a very minium solve the problem OP has. An answer may extend to suggestions regarding Design / Security / Architecture. I mean this in a frendly way - I think your answer is good - just not to OP question :)

Comment: The method you made RajeevKumar will work yes, but the method of JensKloster works too but it much shorter. Just escape them. Only the ' character should be ignore. The other special characters is no problem. I will thank you both! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you execute the SQL by building a SQLCommand object and adding parameters to it, it'll be easier to use special characters as parameters.

There's a good example of how to do this in this related question: [Call a stored procedure with parameter in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542517/call-a-stored-procedure-with-parameter-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

> Because when there is a ' character then the code will fail

Then try this:

```
internal bool AddRecord()
        {
             string SQL = "exec SqlInsert ";

             SQL += "'" + PrepeareForSql(_sqlComputer) + "', ";
             SQL += "'" + PrepeareForSql(_lastUpdatedBy) + "', ";
             SQL += "'" + DateTime.Now + "', ";
             SQL += "'" + PrepeareForSql(_softwareName) + "' ";

             return SqlDatabase.Overig(SQL);
        }

private string PrepeareForSql(string s)
{
   return s.Replace("'","''");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working yes:) Are there more special characters that can make my code fail?

Comment: @Jamie an execelent quistion :) to be fair - don't know, but [others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712070/special-character-in-sql) have had this problem. I have personally never needed to escape other charaters.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to handle ' is just to add .Replace("'", "''").  This will replace all instances of ' with '' which SQL can handle.

```
SQL += "'" + _sqlComputer.Replace("'", "''") + "', ";
SQL += "'" + _lastUpdatedBy.Replace("'", "''") + "', ";
SQL += "'" + DateTime.Now + "', ";
SQL += "'" + _softwareName.Replace("'", "''") + "' ";
```