# Replace specific character from all rows in database column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I've updated a Database and there was an issue with the Excel sheet which added `?` instead of `°` to all items of one column. The column is called `Chemical` and its in a table called `ChemicalResistance`.

Does anybody have an idea how to change this in SQL rather than having to change the whole excel sheet, row by row?

I thought of using `REPLACE` but couldn't get it to work and I'm quite new to SQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special Character in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712070/special-character-in-sql)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
update ChemicalResistance
  set Chemical = replace(Chemical,'?','°')
```

BTW, if only a smaller part of the rows contains that character to replace, it could be a good idea to keep the transaction size down by adding a `WHERE` clause. Simply add the following at the end of the `UPDATE` statement:

```
where CHARINDEX('?', Chemical) > 0
```