# Special Characters like ❷ ❶ ❸ are not storing correctly in SQL even when the type is nVarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I facing a weird issue in SQL. Im trying to save these characters ❷❶❸ into SQL. But its storing as Question Marks (?). The field  is nVarchar.

This is my update query

> update mytable set keywords='key1❶,key2❶,key3❶,key4❶'  where id=50543

Comment: hey can you please try base64encode and decode for store and get.

Comment: Can you help me how to do it in update query?

Comment: can you add your code here so we can better give u result.

Comment: $variable = '❷❶❸';
$encode= base64_encode($variable);
$sql='update tablename set field_name='$encode' where something.'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special Character in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712070/special-character-in-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column should be created as

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (columnname NVARCHAR(40) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI)
```

Then when insert use prefix Unicode character string

```
INSERT INTO mytable (columnname) VALUES (N'❷❶❸')
```

Comment: OK.. I got the issue.. I didnt prefix it with 'N'