# C# + SQL Server: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am writing a client-server app and using a SQL Server database. There is a moment where I need to insert info about new guardian, but something goes wrong.

Here is this piece of code:

```
sqlQuery = $"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Guardians] ([Login], [Password], [AdminAccess]) VALUES (N'{newLogin}', N'{newPassword}', {newAdminAccess})";

cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);

if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
{
    listener.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Success"));
}
else
{
    listener.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Failure"));
}
```

And here is my DB structure:

[DB image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCuaj.png)

I can`t understand where is the mistake for two days, or something like that. Help me please.

Comment: What is the value of `sqlQuery`?

Comment: sqlQuery is just a string, where i put the sql command

Comment: I recommend that you review the [SQL Server data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#unicode-character-strings). The data type in the database is `varchar`, not `nvarchar`.

Comment: I can see that.  What is its value at runtime?  We don't know the values of `newLogin`, `newPassword`, or `newAdminAccess` to know if they're, perhaps, responsible for the syntax error.  What matters is the value of `sqlQuery` that gets passed to the `SqlCommand` constructor.  Also, questions are expected to provide more details than "something goes wrong".

Comment: newLogin newPassword and newAdminAccess are choosed by the user. I have typed "mama" in newLogin and newPassword and 0 in newAdminAccess.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301526/10024425

Comment: Yikes: plain text passwords and SQL injection, two of the biggest security mistakes out there.

Comment: Exception, described in the title appears in this line: if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)

Comment: Would be nice if there was more C# code in the question for context. If I were to guess then `newAdminAccess` is probably a `bool` value, meaning that `sqlQuery` would get set to `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Guardians] ([Login], [Password], [AdminAccess]) VALUES (N'mama', N'someNewPassw0rd', False)`. Instead of injecting tainted user data into SQL queries learn to use Parameterized Queries and use the appropriate overloads of [Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add) to specify the exact types of parameters you're sending to SQL.

Comment: Thanks Joel. I will think how to conclude this problems

Comment: I have changed code according to Joel`s advice and now it works. I still dont know what exactly was wrong, but thanks to Joel I found out about things like SQL injection and hashing. So Joel Coehoorn, you are the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesn't seem to address the question, it does fix two MAJOR security issues and one minor denial of service issue, and in my experience using parameterized queries to fix the SQL injection issue also tends to help with these syntax errors as well. In other words, do it right, and you wouldn't have run into this issue in the first place.

```
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Guardians] ([Login], [Password], [AdminAccess]) VALUES (@Login, @Hash, @Admin)";

//It really is better to create a new connection for most queries. Don't try to re-use it throughout an app. Only re-use the connection string.
using var conn = new SqlConnection("connection string here");
using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);

// Use actual parameter types and lengths here
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Login", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = newLogin;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Hash", SqlDbType.Char, 60).Value = BCrypt.HashPassword(newPassword); // a bcrypt hash is ALWAYS EXACTLY 60 chars
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Admin", SqlDbType.Boolean).Value = newAdminAccess;

conn.Open();
if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
{
    listener.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Success"));
}
else
{
    listener.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Shit"));
}
```

Comment: The `Password` column size (in the database) will have to be modified. According to the image, it's currently defined as `varchar(50)`.