# querying degree symbol ubuntu sql

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, utf-8

I have a db that was designed in french. The ID field is `N°`, which is giving my Ubuntu 16.04 server a really tough time... it can't interpret it correctly, which means that all the dependent queries obviously fail. For the purposes of trouble-shooting, this is the query I want to execute:

`SELECT [N°] FROM PROFIL_LEADERS`

I'm executing this query from the shell using:

`isql -v MY_DSN USERNAME PASS`

The query returns the error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'N°'.

The query DOES WORK on a windows laptop... but NOT for the Ubuntu server.

This is what I've tried:

- In the ODBC connection info for that db I've tried to:

  - set the `charClient_CSet=UTF-8`
  - Change the `Language=French`
  - change the `Charset=utf8`
- I have installed new locales using `sudo locale-gen ISO-8859-1`, and then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`
- I've tried setting the entire locale to `fr_FR`
- I've restarted the server
- I've tried variations on the query:

  - `SELECT N° FROM PROFIL_LEADERS`
  - `SELECT "N°" FROM PROFIL_LEADERS`
  - `SELECT 'N°' FROM PROFIL_LEADERS` (this last one gives me a list of `NÂ` which I assume is how it gets encoded?)
- I have also tried not introducing the degree symbol itself, opting for it's symbol equivalent, but don't seem to get anything either...

This is a microsoft web app db so I can't specify the type of field it is, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712070/special-character-in-sql)

What am I missing?

(FWIW, I'm actually trying to bring this into R... but I figure if I can't even get it in correctly into the server, then R won't work either).

### EDIT: My env variables: (... means supressed)

`ALL=fr_FR
XDG_SESSION_ID=3
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=...
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
LC_ALL=fr_FR
USER=amit
MAIL=/var/mail/amit
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin
PWD=/home/amit
COLLATE=fr_FR
LANG=C.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/amit
LOGNAME=amit
SSH_CONNECTION=...
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001
_=/usr/bin/env`

### EDIT2: showing shell outputs:

`amit@uR-svr:~$ echo Να ζει κανείς ή να μη ζεί
Να ζει κανείς ή να μη ζεί
amit@uR-svr:~$ echo N'°'
N°`

So I guess this shows that the shell IS able to deal w/ the outputs... it's just the sql that isn't?

Comment: Windows is a Unicode OS, since the Windows NT days. SQL Server supports Unicode since day 1. Both started with UCS2 and currently support full UTF16. *Linux* doesn't - it treats everything as `char` arrays and assumes the system's codepage will be set to UTF8 if Unicode support is required. How did you execute this query? What are your environment settings? What are your LC_ALL, LANG and LANGUAGE environment variables? Have you tried setting them to UTF8 ?

Comment: `'N°'` is an ASCII literal. Unicode strings are prefixed by `N`. You should write  `SELECT N'N°'`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As I mentioned, I am querying using `isql` which connects to the db via a SQL Server 13 ODBC connection. I have tried all my `locale` variables in `en_US`, in `fr_FR`, both `UTF-8` and `ISO-8859-1`, nothing interprets the symbol correctly. Updating my post w/ the latest environment settings

Comment: `isql` will send what you provide to it. If the string is already mangled, it will be sent to the server mangled. Have you tried to connect in a different way, eg by using VS Code and the SQL Server extension [as shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-develop-use-vscode)? Were you able to connecto from SSMS on Windows to the server on Ubuntu?

Comment: `LC_ALL=fr_FR`. Try with `LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF8`. Check [How to set up a clean UTF-8 environment in Linux](https://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment)

Comment: I bet if you type `Να ζει κανείς ή να μη ζεί` (To be or not to be in Greek) in your shell you'll get garbled text

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, tried with LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 and still nothing, and the greek entered and didn't get garbled.. but surprisingly didn't give an error. Will read the link u sent.

Comment: Considering it might be an sql issue...I did `man isql` to see what it says about encoding... but it says nothing. Hrm... looked at the `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Servers` that I'm using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/known-issues-in-this-version-of-the-driver and check this out: "If the client encoding is UTF-8, the driver manager does not always correctly convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16. Currently, data corruption will occur when 1 or more characters in the string are not valid UTF-8 characters" Bad news?

Comment: I have to ask why you would name your column like that in the first place. Special characters are a serious PITA to work with in object names. Seems to me like using a better column name would be a much easier approach to a solution.

Comment: @SeanLange from your mouth to God's ears. Because Microsoft in their infinite wisdom have made `N°` the default primary key when working from a French computer. CAN YOU BELIEVE IT????? Already had that fight... can't rename the field once it has data.

Comment: Oh my....that is brilliant!!!

Comment: @AmitKohly what "default primary key" are you talking about? The server doesn't do any such thing. *The developer* writes the creation script, and most developers actually use an autonumbered `ID` field of type bigint. Now, if you say that you got a web app from an MS partner who hired developers that thought it smart to use such symbols ... Or if a biz analyst used the label text as a field name in an app generator to avoid typing the labels because "lazy programmers" ...

Comment: @AmitKohli I'll go as far as say "If you got the database from a Dev (license) Evangelist that only does demos for customers and leaves the real work for partners, engineers". Although in this case, the weird column name actually revealed a restriction that you would never find otherwise - people don't use localized column names and well-written code uses server-bound parameters.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no... I meant exactly what I said. The default autoenumeration field (ID) in Access Web Apps when creating from a French Office 365 account is N°. https://support.office.com/fr-fr/article/Vid%C3%A9o-Cr%C3%A9er-une-application-web-Access-10855ec0-3a12-4e6c-a67c-c88267f00a3c check about 35 seconds in.

Comment: @AmitKohli that's not Microsoft. That's Access Web Apps in SharePoint, a specific feature of a specific product. Which works fine by itself. It also has a strong warning right below the video that Access Web Apps should *not* be used because they are deprecated. Did you create the tables from a template or did you upload an Access database that had `N°` as a field name ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the tables were created by hand, field after field.