# SQL Server - Text truncated if special character is included

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having the following code. Any text which is beyond 8000 characters is being truncated.

```
    declare @a nvarchar(max)
        set @a = 'Random text which exceeds 8000 characters 
                   '+CHAR(176)+' plus special character '

        select @a, Len(@a)
```

It returns 8000 characters but if I remove `CHAR(176)` in above code then it returns correct text

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: prepend it with `= CAST('' as NVARCHAR(MAX))+...` and try again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special Character in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712070/special-character-in-sql)

Comment: It's unclear what is going on from your question. The first string (before the special character) is over 8000 characters? What is 'the correct text'? In either case it should be returning only 8000 characters and a length of 8000. Can you better explain the results you are expecting and what results you are getting?

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce this in SQL Server 2017 -- with or without `CHAR(176)`, string concatenation works without truncation. For earlier versions, your best bet is to explicitly cast *everything* to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` before concatenating it, rather than rely on the whims of implicit conversion. (Using repeated `SET @a += ...` statements with only one operand should also work.)

Comment: Just cast everything to nvarchar, so change `char(176)` to `nchar(176)` and put `N'` before strings.

Comment: @JeroenMostert & lucky Thanks that helped. Doing this worked. set @a = 'Random text  +cast(CHAR(176) as varchar(max))+' '

Comment: It's there but it may not be displaying in your copy of SSMS, depending on version and personal setting. I'm usin V17.8.1 and I see the full string no problem. Replace the final SELECT with PRINT(@a) and you should see the full string.